# powershell script to export all outlook emails from folders/subfolders to csv file

Tags: powershell, outlook, export-to-csv

I need to export all emails from a shared Outlook inbox. The emails are sorted into sub-folders.

I've tried running a PowerShell function in the command window.

```
Function Get-OutlookInBox {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | Out-Null
    $olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]
    $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $Namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
    $Folder = $Namespace.GetDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInBox)
    $Folder.Items |
        Select-Object -Property Subject, ReceivedTime, SenderName,
            SenderEmailAddress |
        Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation XXXX\Trial.csv
}
```

Does not generate a CSV file.

Comment: What you have in the function works for me if I run all the lines independantly.  I don't want all my items in a csv so I ran each line independantly and it exported as expected.

Comment: I am new to powershell. Do I need to save the function to a .ps1 file? What arguments would I need to provide in the command line window?

Comment: once you .dotsource the file you save it to.. you should be able to just call your function Get-OutlookInBox  ... that should create the file you specify on the last line.  AS a tip you might consider putting the filename as a parameter to the function

Comment: instead of .sh most powershell scripts are saved as .ps1 files. Then you can dotsource them in     . \yourscriptname.ps1

Comment: that worked! I need to get all emails from all subfolders ie. flatten the inbox. Do you have any advice on how to modify this function to include this feature?

Comment: without digging into Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass Not sure.

Comment: thanks for your help!

Comment: This module may have some of what you are looking for  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551384/powershell-script-to-export-all-outlook-emails-from-folders-subfolders-to-csv-fi?noredirect=1#comment99686443_56551384   you can find the source for it here: https://github.com/iricigor/OutlookConnector